# fix for memory leak occuring in third party C library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use a a third party C library with interface

`third_party_C_func(const char*)`

I use this function as

```
NSString *content = @"";
const char *cstr = [content cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
third_party_C_func(cstr);
```

Now the Xcode memory leak instrumentation shows a leak **inside** `third_party_C_func` with `malloc`

Is there a way I can clean up this leaked memory?

Also, I do not have the source code meaning I can not build the library leaking memory

Comment: Only if you have the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if there is a true leak within a library, then it must be resolved within that library itself. You cannot generally resolve this yourself. The exception is an old C library that allocates memory and assumes you'll free that memory when you're done with it. But you don't generally see that sort of behavior in Objective-C or Swift libraries.

Having said that, you might want to make sure the library is being used properly. For example, we frequently see people using the SQLite library and posting code that leaks because they failed to call the appropriate clean up method (e.g. if you call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` but never call `sqlite3_finalize`, you can leak).

I might suggest reviewing the library's API (because they might have function designed to free the memory). It's not at all uncommon to have one function that allocates some memory for its internal use but only frees it when you to call some corresponding "clean up" function.

If this library is a mature, commonly used C library, share information about the library and we can probably point you in the right direction. If it is a less mature or uncommon library, then you'll probably have better luck talking directly with the third-party that provided the library.